# Select2 - custom input field in option items, prevent events on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm adding a text input to every option item in a Select2 field with "multiple" enabled and I need to prevent all of the Select2 events when the input is clicked on, both in the dropdown state and in the already selected pill result under any condition.

I've got a start from another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079714/select2-cancel-preventdefault-select2select-at-specific-condition-v-4-0-x) and have attempted to extend it to my needs by trying all of the [Select2 events](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event) but I can't seem to block the event on every single place where the input field is showing.

```
$('#my-select').select2({
    width: '300px',
  multiple: true,
  templateResult: function (item) {
    var $result = $('<span>'+item.text+'</span><input class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here" onclick="test()">');
    return $result;
  },
  templateSelection: function (item) {
    var $result = $('<span>'+item.text+'</span><input class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here" onclick="test()">');
    return $result;
  }
}).on("select2:selecting", function (e) { 
        console.log("selecting",e.params.args.originalEvent);
    if (e.params.args.originalEvent.target.className === 'input') {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6spf32Lx/

This JSFiddle will prevent the Select2 event in the dropdown option, but won't prevent it for an already selected option (where clicking the input will clear the option). Also it won't prevent the event in the pill result's input.

Comment: Added solution for your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for your issue was handling the unselect event 
**select2:unselecting** which can be prevented

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

```js
var stopOpening = false;

$('#my-select').select2({
 width: '300px',
  multiple: true,
  templateResult: function (item) {
    var $result = $('<span class="label">'+item.text+'</span><input class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here" onclick="test()">');
    return $result;
  },
  templateSelection: function (item) {
    var $result = $('<span  class="label">'+item.text+'</span><input class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here" onclick="test()">');
    return $result;a
  }
}).on({
    "select2:unselecting": function(e) {
        console.log("unselecting");
        if (e.params.args.originalEvent.target.className === 'input') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    "select2:opening": function(e) {
        if(stopOpening == true){
            stopOpening = false;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

test = function() {
    console.log("click");
    stopOpening = true;
}
```

```css
.input {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="my-select">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>green</option>
    <option>yellow</option>
    <option>white</option>
    <option>black</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the text entered in the input field when new items are added or when an existing item is deleted? Select2 seems to clear/reinitialize the option items every time they're changed.